# Pinescript Do not enter if the length of green candles(high - low) before entering is more than certain length without security

Tags: pine-script, candlestick-chart, pine-script-v4, candlesticks

I don't want to enter the same situation like image.

[image]

```
CandleSize = abs(high-low)

Length = CandleSize < 30
```

I want to make code to satisfy the condition that applicable only green candle before entry

It would be nice if code could satisfy the condition either the candle before or the one before last

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ta.valuewhen()` for this purpose.

> Returns the value of the `source` series on the bar where the
> `condition` was true on the nth most recent occurrence.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

is_green = close >= open
cond = (math.abs(high-low)) < 30

last_green = ta.valuewhen(is_green, cond, 0)  // If the condition was true on the last green bar
last_green_1 = ta.valuewhen(is_green, cond, 1)  // If the condition was true on the second green from the last bar

should_enter = last_green and last_green_1
plotshape(should_enter, size=size.small)
```